# Java A4 printable document

Tags: java, documentation-generation

I currently use an ActiveX control to print out an html document from a popup window without prompting the user. I've never liked this method and have finally got around to reconsidering the problem.

I've decided to use a Java applet, and have already managed to get the promptless printing working. However, I've no experience with document generation in Java and am trying to get some suggestions for starting points.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to print HTML from a browser (which is what it sounds like you want to do) is to use CSS and define a print specific style sheet.

There a good article on how to do that here http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/